# When using MenuItem in a script why when changing the priority order of the menu item it never change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Generate Guid menu item is all the time in the middle never change it's position. I want it to be above before the Copy or under the Camera at the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateAutomaticGuid : Editor
{
    public static string guid;

    private static Guid uniqueID;

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate Guid", false, -1)]
    private static void GenerateGuid()
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image: Menu item never change the place]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Scriptable API documentation, I think you are using the `MenuItemAttribute` in the wrong way.

> When adding menu items to the "GameObject/" menu for creating custom game objects be sure to call GameObjectUtility.SetParentAndAlign to ensure that the new GameObject is reparented correctly in the case of a context click (see example below). Your function should also call Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo to make the creation undoable and set Selection.activeObject to the newly created object. Also note that in order for a menu item in "GameObject/" to be propagated to the hierarchy Create dropdown and hierarchy context menu, it must be grouped with the other GameObject creation menu items. This can be achieved by setting its priority to 10 (see example below). Note that for legacy purposes MenuItems in "GameObject/Create Other" with no explicit priority set will receive a priority of 10 instead of the default 1000 - we encourage using a more descriptive category name than "Create Other" and explicitly setting the priority to 10.

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/MyCategory/Custom Game Object", false, 10)]
```

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html